# 500 Internal Server Error in Deploying Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my website but I keep getting 500 Internal Server Error. I can open the home page well, but when I want to open another menu tab it keeps showing 500 Internal Server Error. I also have checked the log but didn't seem find any clue. Here's what my server error log showed:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Config Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Hooks Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Utf8 Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> URI Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Router Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> No URI present. Default controller set. 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Output Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Security Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Input Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Language Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Loader Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Config file loaded: application/config/asset.php 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Helper loaded: asset_helper 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Helper loaded: string_helper 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Helper loaded: url_helper 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Helper loaded: form_helper 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Helper loaded: text_helper 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Database Driver Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Native_session Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Form Validation Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Controller Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Model Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Model Class Initialized 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> File loaded: application/views/view_home.php 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> File loaded: application/views/template.php 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Final output sent to browser 
DEBUG - 2013-03-20 11:36:44 --> Total execution time: 0.0295
```

Heres my .httaccess

> RewriteEngine On
>       RewriteBase /indocreweb/
>
> ```
> #Removes access to the system folder by users.
> #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
> #previously this would not have been possible.
> #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /indocreweb/index.php?/$1 [L]
>
> #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
> #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
> #Submitted by: Fabdrol
> #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /indocreweb/index.php?/$1 [L]
>
> #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
> #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
> #request to index.php
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /indocreweb/index.php?/$1 [L] </IfModule>
> ```
>
> #If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
>       #can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
>       #Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
>       ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

From what log showed, I couldn't find any clue what's the problem or what causing it. Anyone have idea about this? :-(

Thank you.

Comment: there seem to be a problem in your.htaccess file

Comment: can u share the site address, so that I can have a look at it?

Comment: check your error log. it'll have details about the 500.

Comment: check htaccess and make sure your rewrite module enabled.

Comment: @raheelshan I added what my htaccess showed above. Please take a look at it. Can you tell me what the problem is? Thank you

Comment: this problem usually comes due .htaccess. I am afraid i dont have any idea about it. You can search on google for this problem.

Comment: @paulfah try removing the .htaccess file and i am sure it will work

Comment: Check .htaccess and can you post your apache error logs for more info

check if your  mod_rewrite is enabled in httpd.conf 
"LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"
remove the comment if it has. check the version of PHP sometimes some file or function which doest seam your issue

Answer (score 0):

from the error it looks like mostly it is happening because of .htaccess
generally every server has mod_rewrite so I don't think the module's being present is an issue.

I think you need to play around with the first line: RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /indocreweb/
try removing the slash, or check even whether the url is correct 
for example if you are accessing the site directly then it should be
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / 
like www.indocreweb.com

But if it's being accessed as a sub folder or something like www.indocreweb.com/indocreweb
then 
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /indocreweb

Hope this helps.